# Why did SO's (and SF's) traffic level off?

Tags: discussion, traffic

If you look at the stats for all time on Quantcast:

https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#!traffic

and select 'All' for the date range, traffic shows steady growth until about March 2013, then it levels off.  Serverfault's traffic shows the same thing?

What happened?

Comment: Select "all" - it does this every year. Summer vacation...

Comment: It also levelled off during the same time period (June, July and August), in 2012, 2011, and 2010.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about lower traffic in summer.

Comment: Summer vacations start in March ?

Comment: Looking at SO's traffic, I could accept summer vacation, but ServerFault's traffic plummeted in March this year, not at all the same pattern as previous summers.  Not sure how SF's much lower traffic plays into this...

Comment: "Plummet" doesn't seem like a fair characterization of the summer vacation traffic.  New Year's day and Christmas, on the other hand... *those do* look like plummets.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed; this seems to be _exactly_ about StackExchange.

Comment: @Emrakul, lower traffic during summer is not specific to the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: This definitely applies to me - I don't even have access to a computer! :P All my activity since a month or so ago has been from mobile :P

Comment: @Fréd No, the _question_ is about SE. The _answer_ applies to all sites.